# My ul and li are not working

Tags: html, css

These are my html codes:

```
<ul class="mymenu">
    <div class="gradient rounded-corners grpelem" id="u7149">
        <!-- simple frame -->
    </div>
    <li><a href="degree-programs.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="diploma-programs.html">Programs Offered</a></li>
    <li><a href="diploma-programs.html">Military</a></li>
    <li><a href="diploma-programs.html">About Us </a></li>
    <li><a href="diploma-programs.html">Locations</a></li>
    <li><a href="diploma-programs.html">Request Info</a></li>
</ul>
```

These are my Css codes for above html:

```
ul.mymenu {
    list-style:none;
}

ul.mymenu li {
    float:left;
}

ul.mymenu li a {
    color:#fff;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by not working? What are you trying to accomplish and what are you observing?

Comment: Please read this: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You are setting the `color: #FFF;`, unless you have a background color that is not white it will look invisible.

Comment: Please visit http://shakil.comuv.com/dennis/  @PalinDrome555

Comment: You cannot put a `div` as a direct child of an `ul`...only `li` are allowed.

Comment: I would run your page through a validator, it will identify any markup errors. [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_uri)

Answer (score 2):

It seems you have a mistake in your css which is the reason why the list is not visible. Change your ul.mymenu li as follows:

```
ul.mymenu li a {

    color: black; //you had typed the colorcode wrong and it was white so it was not visible to you on white background

 }
```

Comment: Please visit http://shakil.comuv.com/dennis/

Comment: This isn't the right answer, though you did good with the limited amount of info you got. See his website to see his problem'